# What do the Rings of Power actually do to the races that wear them?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

So, I've been reading Lord of The Rings, and other Tolkien books, and I've always wondered something. What did the other rings of power, given to the various races by Sauron actually do?

Comment: [Here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/what-special-powers-did-the-dwarf-rings-give-their-users) be the Dwarven rings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the ring of power have any other power than to turn you invisible in Lord of the Rings?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/does-the-ring-of-power-have-any-other-power-than-to-turn-you-invisible-in-lord-o)

Comment: @TravisChristian - not a dupe because the other question relates to the One Ring; this one is for the 3, the 7 and the 9.

Comment: @JimmyShelter I'm not sure that it should be closed, but it's worth nothing that the answers are as closely bound together as the rings themselves. See also these two: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12830/572 http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3762/572

Comment: The top answer of the possible duplicate directly addresses this question as well.

Comment: I'd say a closer duplicate to [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45954/sauron-giving-the-rings-to-different-races), perhaps?  ("*Why did the races accept the rings and what did they expect from them?*")

Comment: The title should probably be "do for" rather than "do to".

Answer (score 24):

This is covered in Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age in the published Silmarillion.

For Men:

> Men proved easier to ensnare. Those who used the Nine Rings became mighty in their day, kings, sorcerers, and warriors of old. They obtained glory and great wealth, yet it turned to their undoing. They had, as it seemed, unending life, yet life became unendurable to them. They could walk, if they would, unseen by all eyes in this world beneath the sun, and they could see things in worlds invisible to mortal men; but too often they beheld only the phantoms and delusions of Sauron. And one by one, sooner or later, according to their native strength and to the good or evil of their wills in the beginning, they fell under the thraldom of the ring that they bore and under the domination of the One, which was Sauron's. And they became for ever invisible save to him that wore the Ruling Ring, and they entered into the realm of shadows. The Nazgûl were they, the Ringwraiths, the Enemy's most terrible servants; darkness went with them, and they cried with the voices of death.

For Dwarves:

> The Dwarves indeed proved tough and hard to tame; they ill endure the domination of others, and the thoughts of their hearts are hard to fathom, nor can they be turned to shadows. They used their rings only for the getting of wealth; but wrath and an over-mastering greed of gold were kindled in their hearts, of which evil enough after came to the profit of Sauron. It is said that the foundation of each of the Seven Hoards of the Dwarf-kings of old was a golden ring; but all those hoards long ago were plundered and the Dragons devoured them, and of the Seven Rings some were consumed in fire and some Sauron recovered.

The Elven rings were a special case, as Sauron *didn't* give those to the Elves; instead, Sauron wasn't even involved in their making, and the Elves had managed to protect them so that he never even touched them.  Nonetheless:

> Now these were the Three that had last been made, and they possessed the greatest powers. Narya, Nenya, and Vilya, they were named, the Rings of Fire, and of Water, and of Air, set with ruby and adamant and sapphire; and of all the Elven-rings Sauron most desired to possess them, for those who had them in their keeping could ward off the decays of time and postpone the weariness of the world. But Sauron could not discover them, for they were given into the hands of the Wise, who concealed them and never again used them openly while Sauron kept the Ruling Ring. Therefore the Three remained unsullied, for they were forged by Celebrimbor alone, and the hand of Sauron had never touched them; yet they also were subject to the One.

And finally, as a general property of all of the Rings of Power:

> And all those rings that he governed he perverted, the more easily since he had a part in their making, and they were accursed, and they betrayed in the end all those that used them.

Comment: so, the real answer is that, except for invisibility and long-life, Tolkien was deliberately vague about their actual powers (like everything else magical in Middle Earth).

Comment: it's interesting to note there were other Elvish rings of power, just of lesser power. "of all the Elven-rings Sauron most desired to possess them [the Three]" so there were others he desired less

Comment: Did all the rings give invisibility or just the one ring?

Comment: @childcat15: There apparently were many elvish rings of power, some lesser and some greater. "In Eregion long ago many Elven-rings were made, magic rings as you call them, and they were, of course, of various kinds: some more potent and some less. The lesser rings were only essays in the craft before it was full-grown, and to the Elven-smiths they were but trifles..." The Great Rings were also made by the Elves with Sauron's assistance and also perverted by him.

Answer (score 0):

The Elven rings did not make their wearers invisible, but the rings themselves could be so.

The Dwarven rings apparently did not, but the Human rings definitely did. The Nazgul were invisible except for their black cloaks and armor and weapons.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have a source for any of this?  The quote in the previous answer describes how invisibility was _one_ property of the Nine, but mentions other properties as well.  The Seven and Three had their own distinct properties.  But more specifically, the question asks about the effect of the rings _on_ their wearers, as distinct from the powers they bestow.

Comment: @DavidW: the seven and the nine are exactly the same. The effects varied only because they were given to different races.

Comment: @Shamshiel You may be right and I simply don't recall that.  I don't remember reading an enumeration of all the granted (available) powers, instead of just a description of (some of?) what was done with the rings.  Men and Dwarves used their rings differently, and suffered different outcomes.  I can't tell if that's down to difference between the rings, difference between the races, or some combination of both.  (Which may be a deficiency in my grasp of the lore or in my memory.)